# SAS macro loop and dummy variable

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I just want to make new dummy variable when there is a certain value.

Here is my orignal data example.

```
ID A1 A2... A10
1  10   1    5
2  20   8   4
...
...
```

And I would like to add dummy variable when there is a certain value in those attributes.
For example, ID 1 subject have "10", a new variable, Add10 would be 1..

```
ID A1 A2.. A10 Add1..Add4 Add5...Add20

1  10   1.. 5  1  ...0   1  ...    0

2   20  8.. 4  0  ...1   0  ...     1

...
```

Here is my code..

```
%MACRO DO_LIST;
%DO I=1 %TO 20;

data aaaa;
set aa33; 
if A1 =i or
A2 =i or
A3 =i or
...
A10 =i then Add&I=I ;
RUN;
%END;  
%MEND DO_LIST;
%DO_LIST;
```

However, my result have only Add20, which is the last variable..
I feel I took a mistake in loop statement. Would you mind helping me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're always using the same data set as the input to `aaaa` and you're not changing this dataset with each loop.   Thus, you'll always get Add20 only as this is what the last iteration of the loop will do.

A simple fix to this would be:

```
data append;
 set aa33;
run;

%MACRO DO_LIST;
%DO I=1 %TO 20;
data append; 
 set append;
 if A1 =i or
 A2 =i or
 A3 =i or
 .....
 A10 =i then Add&I=I ; 
RUN;
%END;
%MEND DO_LIST;
%DO_LIST;
```

You want pretty much add a column to your dataset each time the loop runs as opposed to entirely replacing it with the original dataset (`aa33`) and the results of only the current iteration.

If you know the max # is 20,  the following should work without a macro

```
data test;
 set aa33;
 array add[20] 1. add1 - add20;
 array a[*] a:;

do i = 1 to dim(a);
  value = a[i];
  add[value] = 1;
end;
run;
```

I think that's what you're looking for, it'd help if you'd fill in at least the first two full rows of your example.